# How to read a column of 'dictionary' into pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file with a column whose type is a dictionary (column 'b' in the example below). But **b** in **df** is a string type even though I define it as the dictionary type. I didn't find the solution to this question. Any suggestions?

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[{'a':3, 'haha':4}, {'c':3}, {'d':4}]})
a.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=None)
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', dtype={'b':dict})
```

Comment: [Is there](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dtypes) a dtype _dict_ in pandas?

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It seems there is not _dict_ in pandas. But is there any way to read dictionary into pandas?

Comment: No, because pandas can't know without "interpreting" the string if it's a dict (or any valid python type). And "interpreting" strings can be tricky buisness because you could execute malicious code. So you probably shouldn't try to roundtrip arbitary python objects. Try to use "native" pandas or NumPy types.

Comment: Personally, would try to use apply on the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder if your CSV column is actually meant to be a Python dict column, or rather JSON.  If it's JSON, you can read the column as `dtype=str`, then use [`json_normalize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) on that column to explode it into multiple columns.  This is an efficient solution assuming the column contains valid JSON.

Comment: Could you suggest an example? Was unsuccessful with converting dictionary in a column.

Comment: @PavelFedotov: You should post your own question, I'm sure someone can help you if you have a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

There is no dictionary type in pandas. So you should specify `object` in case you want normal Python objects:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', dtype={'b':object})
```

This will contain strings because pandas doesn't know what dictionaries are. In case you want dictionaries again you could try to "eval" them with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) (safe string evaluation):

```
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

print(df['b'][0]['a'])  # 3
```

If you're really confident that you never ever run this on untrusted csvs you could also use `eval`. But before you consider that I would recommend trying to use a `DataFrame` only with "native" pandas or NumPy types (or maybe a `DataFrame` in `DataFrame` approach). Best to avoid `object` dtypes as much as possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the *converters* parameter.
From the documentation:

> **converters : dict, optional**
>
> Dict of functions for converting values in certain columns. Keys can
> either be integers or column labels.

If you know your column is well formed and includes no missing values then you could do:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', converters = {'b': ast.literal_eval})
```

However, for safety (as others have commented) you should probably define your own function with some basic error resilience:

```
def to_dict(x):
    try:
        y = ast.literal_eval(x)
        if type(y) == dict:
            return y
    except:
        return None
```

and then:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv', converters = {'b': to_dict})
```