# How to read a column in the format of dictionaty in a .csv file in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file, the second column is in the format of a dictionary (See the example below for a row in that column). I am trying to read the column as a dictionary type by following [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446709/how-to-read-a-column-of-dictionary-into-pandas), but the column is still in the object type.

```py
{
    "cap": {
        "english": 0.8018818614025648,
        "universal": 0.5557322218336633
    },
    "display_scores": {
        "english": {
            "astroturf": 0.0,
            "fake_follower": 4.1,
            "financial": 1.5,
            "other": 4.7,
            "overall": 4.7,
            "self_declared": 3.2,
            "spammer": 2.8
        },
        "universal": {
            "astroturf": 0.3,
            "fake_follower": 3.2,
            "financial": 1.6,
            "other": 3.8,
            "overall": 3.8,
            "self_declared": 3.7,
            "spammer": 2.3
        }
    },
    "raw_scores": {
        "english": {
            "astroturf": 0.0,
            "fake_follower": 0.81,
            "financial": 0.3,
            "other": 0.94,
            "overall": 0.94,
            "self_declared": 0.63,
            "spammer": 0.57
        },
        "universal": {
            "astroturf": 0.06,
            "fake_follower": 0.64,
            "financial": 0.3133333333333333,
            "other": 0.76,
            "overall": 0.76,
            "self_declared": 0.74,
            "spammer": 0.47
        }
    },
    "user": {
        "majority_lang": "en",
        "user_data": {
            "id_str": "11330",
            "screen_name": "test_screen_name"
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I did for now:

```py
import pandas as pd
import ast
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\daiyaxin\Desktop\python_botometer\result_Dec_16.csv", dtype={'bot_score':object})
df['bot_score'] = df['bot_score'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` will work if you're dealing with a Python dict instead of JSON. If it's JSON you can use `pd.json_normalize` instead. Your code seems on the right track. What exactly is not working?

Comment: @AbirbhavG. Thanks for the reply. I am actually trying to get the values of the first key (cap). After using the code to transfer the object into dictionary, I use `df.info()` to check the type of the column, and it is still an object column. So I cannot treat it as a dictionary and extract the values that I cared. I guess maybe the column that I want to transfer is not in the exact format of dictionary, because there are not [] in it. But in dictionary, there are [] inside (). Do you have any other suggestions? (Sorry if I asked some silly questions)

Comment: Share a small reproducible example from your CSV

Comment: @YaxinDai If  `df['bot_score'] = df['bot_score'].apply(ast.literal_eval)` works without errors, everything is fine. Because pandas does not have a column type called dictionary. You can check the type of a value instead of a column: `print(type(df['bot_score'].iloc[0]))` Probably it will return: `<class 'dict'>`